# How to forget/remove username in Windows 8 Store - account deleted

Tags: windows-8, windows-store, microsoft-account

I deleted a Windows Live/Microsoft account (I have others) that I was using for the Windows Store on one of my PCs.  Now I can't use the store at all because it wants a password for that particular account - there is no sign out option nor is there a "change username" option that I can see.  When I click the "Sign in" button, the store insists on using the deleted account.

So, to summarize, Windows Store is insisting I sign into an account that no longer exists.

How do I get the store to delete it?

Steps taken so far:

- Removing the Live account from the local Credential Manager
- Removing mention of this account in the IdentityCRL registry folder
- Resetting the store cache using wsreset

I think this is a bug but Microsoft Connect isn't accepting bugs or feature requests for Windows 8 right now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Windows 8 interface, you would need to go to PC settings -> Users. If you don't already have a local account, click Switch to a local account. It will require you to create a local username and password and re-sign in. From there, you probably want to restart the computer. You can then go to the same place in Settings to "Switch to a Microsoft Account." You'll need to enter the credentials of the new Microsoft account to login.

I found a walkthrough of the procedure below. You'll have to go to the second part to start with, but it works the same.
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/switch-between-local-and-microsoft-accounts/

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Thanks for your ideas; this account is a domain account, though, so I can't switch to a Microsoft Account and then switch back to a local account.