# Windows 10 - remove account from windows store sign in list

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, windows-store

I signed in to my account in the Windows Store app on a friend's computer. Now when I click the "Sign in" option, it still has my account listed under "Use this account".

I would like to remove my account from this list.

I have tried some things from [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/628142/how-to-forget-remove-username-in-windows-8-store-account-deleted), including:

- Removing 2 references to the account from the local Credential Manager
- Removing mention of this account in the IdentityCRL registry folder
- Resetting the store cache using wsreset

but none have removed the account from the list. In case it is unclear, this is a screenshot of the list I am trying to remove my account from:

[image: list]

Edit: it looks like this list is common across multiple store apps, eg. if i open the xbox app it comes up in the same "sign in" window in that app too.

Comment: You linked the user profile to a MS account or you logged into the just Windows Store?  Have they tried logged into their account

Comment: I did not link the user profile - it is still a local user profile. They have no windows store account - it was blank before I logged in (no cached/saved accounts) and I just wanted to remove mine from the list. I guess this is a good lesson - don't sign in on a shared/public computer.