# Remove an account from "Microsoft: Pick an account" screen

Tags: user-accounts, microsoft-edge, microsoft-account, microsoft

Somebody used my computer for a one-time sign in to a service which requires Microsoft Account. Now every time I want to sign in to the same service, I see that person account in "Microsoft: Pick an account" screen:

[image]

How to get rid of it? How to remove that single account, so I can see only mine?

Things that I have tried so far:

1. Logging to that account and logging-off brings no solution.
2. I am using Microsoft Edge, but removing stored credentials from Edge Password Manager / Microsoft Wallet does not remove this item.
3. A very similar [question was asked here](https://superuser.com/q/1238273/156554) six and a half year ago, but it has no answer so far.
4. All guides that I have found in the Internet says about removing an account from a PC, using  *Settings* → *Accounts* → *Email & accounts* application.

That's not an option in my case. Neither of accounts in "Pick an account" appears there. I don't want to remove an account from my PC or Windows. I just want to remove it from Edge's / Microsoft Account's "remind" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to https://myapplications.microsoft.com and log in as your main user.
Click the `...` next to the other username(s) in the list of users

[image]

Choose 'Forget'.

Comment: It may also be listed in Windows -> Settings -> Accounts -> School or work account. This happens if someone logged in, and got the question: Do you to manage your account, and they click the big blue ok button, rather than the text link: No, don't manage account.

Comment: @LPChip Are you 100% sure that such account (which only logged in through Edge browser and never through Windows) will appear in that _system_ list?

Comment: @trejder I'm 100% sure this will happen if you login in Microsoft Office. If that did not happen, only Edge browser, you will not get it in windows. I used the word may so you can check it. You did not mention that it was only used in MS Edge and not Office. Also, other people may find this answer and this comment may actually help them.